# klocwork : kwconan fails with "Error: Cannot proceed: Cannot validate tables"

Tags: static-analysis, klocwork

I'm trying to run a local klocwork scan on my code base, but I keep failing.

My steps:

> 1. kwinject make
> 2. kwbuildproject --url https://hostname:8080/project -tables-directory KW_Tables kwinject.out
> 3. kwconan run --tables-directory KW_Tables --url https://hostname:8080/project --json

Note: the real hostname is not shown in the pasted commands here.

The last command (kwconan) always fails with the following error:

> "Error: Cannot proceed: Cannot validate tables"

I tried to look online but I failed to find any useful documentation.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

reviewing the build.log present in /KW_Tables may help.

if it doesn't help please reach out Klocwork support. They may share the correct parameters to be passed.